# sending s3 file as an attachment in mailx

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-s3

I am trying to send a S3 file as an attachment using mailx , I have below command which works fine for sending a normal file on unix file system, but how to use it with a s3 file system.

```
mailx -r ${from} -a ${file_path_attach} -s "${subject}" "${recipients}" << EOM

${message}
EOM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to do it as below.

also make sure the email functions are installed on the cluster you are trying to run mailx command

```
#move the S3 file to local DIR on AWS
s3cmd get S3:attach.txt /tmp/attach.txt

#send the email with attachment
mailx -r test@test.com -a /tmp/attach.txt -s "TEST Subject" "test@test.com" << EOM

TEST body
EOM
```